# How to orderBy a calculated column in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a `products` talbes which has columns `price1`, `price2`, etc. I want to order the table by `1 - (price1 / price2)` and select say 10 records from 11th row.

How can I achieve something like `SELECT *, 1 - (price1 / price2) AS discount FROM products ORDER BY discount` in `Laravel Eloquent`?

Currently I'm using [`Accessor`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to calculate discount and using [`sortBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortby) to order the entire product collection, which means even if I only need 10 reocrds, I have to select the entire table first. As I have ~20k records, my approach is extremely slow (took ~10s on an 1CPU and 0.5GB ram vps). So I'm thinking calculate the discount in the query rather than using `Accessor`. Anyone know how to do this in `Eloquent`? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `orderByRaw('1 - (price1 / price2)')`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel exactly what I needed, thanks